# Typescript - Importing Express not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, require

I have this in my app with the `@types/express` dependency installed

`import express = require('express');`

It is pointing to the `express` and saying `this is an unexpected identifier` when I run my server. I believe this is correct TS syntax and the regular JS way of `const express = ..` has the same error.

Do I need regular express? or wouldn't I need the one I already installed, which should be for TS specifically?

Answer (score 24):

To replace `require` statement with `import` statement, for example:

```
    const express = require('express');
```

You can convert it to this:

```js
    import * as express from "express";
```

And yes, you need both, regular `express` as dependency and `@types/express` as dev-dependency to have TypeScript type definitions working.

Answer (score 20):

The syntax you want will be

```
import express from "express";
```

and it shouldn't result in a duplicate identifier error unless its simply a IDE bug. You can look into a common setup most people use to work with NodeJS/Typescript here.

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter

Comment: appreciate the answer, it's still giving me that same error when run server.ts

Comment: Hmmm make sure you're building your application with "tsc" and make sure your file extension is ".ts"

Comment: gotcha, yeah i have a `tsconfig.json` file generated by `tsc --init` and also have a `server.ts` file that has that import statement

Comment: Hmmm.... its tough to say for sure what it is... the fact that it says the regular JS way is also an error makes me suspect it's like an invalid character somewhere in the file above the import or something "this is an unexpected identifier"

Answer (score 0):

I had a particularly difficult situation because I was using esmodules with our production/development, but commonjs with our testing tools.

I ended up getting it to work by using both imports.

**app.ts**

```
import express, * as express_test from "express"

const app = express ? express() : express_test()
```

Answer (score 0):

this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-express-in-typescript/) helped me a bunch, primarily w/r to the `module: "commonjs"` package.json entry