# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype') React Typescript + Express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, express

I'm trying to use express at my React-Typescript SPA. But It's giving me the error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
(anonymous function)
node_modules/express/lib/response.js:42
  39 |  * @public
  40 |  */
  41 | 
> 42 | var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
  43 | 
  44 | /**
  45 |  * Module exports.
```

I've tried adding `target: "node"` to my  `"node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js"` But it won't work...

Here's some ways I've already tried to solve it:

```
    import express from "express";
    app = express();
---------------
    import express from "express";
    let app: express.Application;
    app = express();
-------------

    import express from "express";
    let app: any;
    app = express();

-------------
    const express require("express");
    let app: express.Application;
    app = express();
```

Comment: I think the problem is you forgot to instantiate `app` with const, var, or let for the first example, since it should work.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56880311/typescript-importing-express-not-working

Comment: @KennethLew sorry I copied incorrectly, but my I was using const app = express()

Comment: @KennethLew I saw that post, but It didn't work for me...

Comment: perhaps try `import * as express from "express"`

Comment: @KennethLew  still won't do it...

Comment: How did you fix it?!

Comment: I didn't. I switched to axios... =/

Answer (score 9):

You have to instantiate both the app and express, use the const keyword as well.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

Also, look for anywhere in your code base where you have:

```
import { response } from 'express';
```

Often this is put in by mistake and removing this line may solve the error

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was this thing:
"import { response } from 'express".
Spent an hour looking for the problem, you saved me a log of time)

Answer (score 3):

Faced same issue

it was imported under

```
import e from "express";
```

not sure cuz of any random IntelliSense extension or maybe the GH copilot auto-completion

Comment: YES my VSCode added that line to the top of my file randomly.... thank you !

Answer (score 0):

faced the same issue

```
var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
```

change it to

```
let res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
```

Comment: That's interesting, I wonder why changing from *function scoped* to *block scoped* fixes the problem?